# Why are the Planck charge and Planck mass values so much larger than observed particles?

Tags: mass, charge, dimensional-analysis, physical-constants, order-of-magnitude

The Planck charge and mass values seem rather unusual.  Is this an indicator that there is a lack of understanding in current theory, or is there a logical explanation for the magnitude of these two numbers?  I read in a paper by Forsythe, that Planck mass might be the geometric mean between the mass of the smallest possible particle and the mass of the universe.  Could this be correct?

Comment: Link to the paper you mention, although frankly that sounds like nonsense to me.

Comment: *"Could this be correct? "* - how could we know?

Comment: The large value of the Planck mass is a reflection of the weakness of gravitational interactions.

Comment: http://vixra.org/abs/1306.0045

Comment: Any comments on the meaning behind Planck charge.  This value seems so unlikely?

Comment: The Planck charge is the quantum limit for the value of the classical electric charge. There is no reason for it to be very small, because the electric charge is a quantum number that makes no sense as a small fraction. The intuition for the Planck charge is the lower limit on the electric charge of subatomic particles. It is only 4 times smaller then the charge of the down quark thus being in the right range. Also, most Planck units are actually huge rather than small: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_units#Derived_units

Comment: Kind of echoing AlfredCentauri, but I don't think it's possible to objectively answer (within the realm of currently accepted theories) a question like "Is this an indicator that there is a lack of understanding in current theory?" It may go to opinion-based stuff, which is off topic. You should consider removing that part of the question; it's a bit misleading. In the future, if such points are necessary, an answerer will probably mention in their post that the reasons for (whatever) are still disputed/open for debate.

Comment: Note that the paper you've linked is hosted on vixra, which does not do any peer review of the papers & is often filled with crackpot papers.